# Bp-reshare alternative

Tags: buddypress

I used the plugin bp-reshare that you can download the latest version [here](https://github.com/imath/bp-reshare/releases/tag/1.0-beta5) 
but this plugin doesn't work when you add media with rtmedia which is a most have plugin when using buddypress so is there some other alternatives to share content between users or is there someone pro enough to modify the core bp-reshare plugin

Thank you

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Go to Dashboard > Settings > Buddypress > Settings 
Check rtMedia update and save settings.

[image]

Comment: i dont see this option ,,  thers is no such a box to check

Comment: See screenshot above. This is a fresh install with only the latest Wordpress, Buddypress, rtMedia, and bp-reshare. Maybe you should do a fresh install and start again or deactivate any possible conflicting plugins.

Comment: plz can you give me the link to rtmedia and bp-reshare download pages ,,, because i made a fresh install with the latest versions of only the needed plugins but still dont have these options available,,, sorry for my ignorence

Comment: Here you go. https://github.com/imath/bp-reshare https://wordpress.org/plugins/buddypress-media/